# how do i add a machine-$(CONFIG_FOO_BAR) for my board info file?

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel, driver

I see that in the directory kernel/arch/arm there are a lot of board files, which I am using as reference for my i2c driver. I have the following code in a directory I made called `./mach-foo` and I want to add it to the make file so my driver will work.
Here are the contents:
`./mach-foo/foo-dummy.c` has module init and exit and a basic i2c struct and probe, does printk's to confirm calls

```
$ cat ./mach-foo/Makefile
obj-m       += foo_dummy.c
```

Now I need to know how `mach-foo` will get compiled or built or what ever (my understanding is limited). Looking at the makefile already in place in `kernel/arch/arm/Makefile` I see that other folders are added via a line similar to 
`machine-$(CONFIG_FOO_BAR)       := foobar`

I am familiar with the operation of Kconfig, and that it decideds what come with `CONFIG_FOO_BAR` 
I was hoping that I could just hard-code a line like

`machine-m   :=foo` does this work?

I saw that the Makefile automatically appends `mach-` to the name here, so are `machine-m` or `machine-y` valid?

 Also, do I need `:=` or `+=`?

Comment: Yes, you can hard-code 'y' instead of the $(CONFIG_FOO_BAR).  The CONFIG_* macros are typically defined in the .config file.  This file is created by running 'make menuconfig'.  It will get this config information from pre-defined config templates.  You can also hand-edit this .config file, but some build trees will overwrite it during a build prep.

Comment: Thank you again peter, you sir are a gentleman, scholar, and saint.